# Scope of range variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, scope

Consider the following statement:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tblA a 
WHERE a.Name = @Name 

UNION 

(SELECT a.* 
 FROM tblB 
 WHERE a.Name = @Name)
```

Notice that range variables (aka aliases) for two different tables have been given the same name.

Is there any potential for conflict or ambiguity in doing this? Should all range variables (aliases) be given a unique name within the statement e.g.:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tblA a 
WHERE a.Name = @Name 

UNION 

(SELECT b.* 
 FROM tblB 
 WHERE b.Name = @Name)
```

Experience has shown that this has worked so far... that the scope of each range variable (alias) does not appear to span across the UNION, but is this dependent on unsupported behavior, or do range variables (aliases) have formally defined scope relevant to cases like this?

Comment: If the first query works, I'm surprised. Though IF it works it would be the same os only have the first select without the union.

Comment: will this even work

Comment: Both the queries will not even execute

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've verified it works. Since I don't actually have two tables with the same structure, instead of using `SELECT a.*` I used `SELECT a.SiteID FROM tblA a   UNION SELECT a.SiteID FROM tblB a`. It returned the expected number of rows.

Comment: @H.Fadlallah The [tag:sql] and [tag:tsql] tags were probably enough. (If we add too many tags, each tag becomes less useful for searching.)

Answer (score 3):

You threw me with the term "range variable". I've always seen that construct called an "alias".

I'm no expert on SQL standards, but I can't fathom an interpretation where a database engine would ever have a problem with re-used table aliases. Each SELECT statement before and after the UNION is just that - a fully functioning, complete SELECT statement. The two statements are wholly independent from one another - neither knows anything about the other. There is no way to correlate a row from the first query with a row from the second, so I don't see how the aliases could interfere with one another.

You have demonstrated it works on SQL Server.

I tried it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2b56/2), and it works with MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. Unfortunately Oracle and MS SQL Server are broken on the fiddle site, so no way to test there.

Comment: Here it is on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/CYXS90514) (Microsoft SQL Server 2014). It works.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I learned the term in connection with a different database product.